# How to Retrieve a list of the most-viewed channels by region?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

I did go through Youtube v3 APIs  but couldn't figure out  how to achieve something which can be done using v2 APIs easily i.e. get all most-viewed channels in  a region for e.g. Sweden here

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/channelstandardfeeds/SE/most_viewed?v=2

Comment: You can look for it [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/videos#videos-retrieve-most-popular-videos). You must set the `chart` parameter to `mostPopular` then put `regionCode` and `videoIdCategory`.

Comment: thanks @gerardnimo however that gives me the most popular video in the region .I want to get the most viewed or most subscribed channel in the region .Can you help me with any pointers on that .

Comment: I see, I mistook video for a channel. Let me see what I can get.

Comment: Is there no way to achieve this?