# Use Youtube API to get a top channels for each category

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm currently trying to build a simple app that lists the top n channels for each category using the YouTube API. The problem I'm currently facing is that I don't know what query would give me the top channels for a given category.

I've already tried using the [guideCategories](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/guideCategories) resource to get every channel category. A basic query would give me every category. I would then use the name of each category and use the [Search](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search) resource (setting q to the name of the category)  to get what I think is a list  of the top channels. I think I'm doing it wrong though because I've seen several resources like [SocialBlade](https://socialblade.com/youtube/top/category/entertainment) that show a completely different list of channels.

***Does anyone have any idea on how I could get closer to the end goal of getting top channels for a specific category?***

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any documentation about getting the top channels for specific category. You can only get the [top videos within a channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39512382/how-to-get-top-10-videos-from-your-channel-with-the-views-count-included-in-the). I've also seen this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35437243/how-to-retrieve-a-list-of-the-most-viewed-channels-by-region) which discussed on how to retrieve a list of the most-viewed channels by region.